# Flutter navigator push in initstate going into the loop

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, navigator

I'm trying to redirect to another page if data is missing on the main page, but he goes into the loop and works all the time

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
   _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .document(widget.firebaseUser.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => _onMeUpdate(snapshot));
}

void _onMeUpdate(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
       _gender = snapshot.data['gender'] ?? '';
       _match = snapshot.data['match'] ?? '';
       Future(() {
          if (_gender.isEmpty) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => Page1(
                    firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser)));
          } else {
            if (_match.isEmpty) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2(
                      firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser)));
            }
          }
        });
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding my answer, I leave the answer to whatever happens to you.

It happened when he put pushReplacement in place of a push

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2(
                      firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => 
Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute( builder: (BuildContext context) => 
Page2(firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser))));
```